# Solve The Triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having a tough time trying to solve this problem.

I have utilized the 30, 60, 90 triangle measures for the length of sides. However, I am stuck since the side that would be √3 has 100 as its length. How do I solve then? [image]

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

Comment: Where you write $\sqrt 3$ in your working, you want to replace it with 100.

Comment: If the length that you have marked as hypotenuse=y, then y=100/sin 30 and x=y/sin 60

Comment: Ok I just did that. I multiplied 100 (1/2) = 50. That can't be right. That would mean that one of the sides is larger than the hypotenuse?

Comment: @user137452,100/(1/2)=200

Comment: You are looking at the hypotenuse all wrong, and so the miscalculations. hypotenuse is supposed to be the side opposite to the right angle, or $x$ in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Let's name the triangle as $\triangle ABC$ which is right angled at B so that $x$ is hypotenuse. And this is a 30-60-90 triangle.

Let the perpendicular from B, drop on the Hypotenuse at D giving $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BDC$, and both of these small triangle are 30-60-90 triangle. So, apply the trignometry identities.

The length $x$ will be $$=100\cdot tan 30^\circ+100 \cdot tan 60^\circ$$

Or, $$100 \cdot {\frac{4}{\sqrt 3}}$$

A little hint, remembering sin, cos and tan identities and values is lot simple and elegant than remembering thew cosec, sec and cot values.

Comment: Stupid question but how did you recognize that the angle where both the triangles meet was 90 degrees?

Comment: It is a perpendicular BD on AC :)

Comment: Would you mind drawning that for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If only I knew how to draw in the answer, I would have already done it. Let me find out..

Comment: Forget it. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

To find $x$ here, you will need to look at this as 2 separate triangles, and find the base of each separate triangle, then add the bases up to get $x$.

For the triangle on the left hand side, we can use the $\tan(x)$ function to relate the $60^{\circ}$ angle with the opposite side of length 100, and our adjacent side, which we are looking for (let's call it $y$).

So, we know $\tan(x) = \dfrac{\text{opp}}{\text{adj}}$, and this gives $\tan(60^{\circ}) = \dfrac{100}{y}$.  But $\tan(60^{\circ}) = \sqrt{3}$, so we have:

$\sqrt{3} = \dfrac{100}{y}$, and solving for $y$ gives $y = \dfrac{100}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Now, we need to solve for the adjacent side of the triangle on the right-hand side using the angle $30^{\circ}$.  Again, we want to relate the opposite side of $30^{\circ}$ to its adjacent side (the unknown -- we can call it $z$).  We will have to use $\tan(x)$ again.  So we get:

$\tan(30^{\circ}) = \dfrac{\text{opp}}{\text{adj}} = \dfrac{100}{z}$.  But, $\tan(30^{\circ}) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so we have the equation:

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \dfrac{100}{z}$ and solving for $z$ gives:

$z = \dfrac{100}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} = 100\sqrt{3}$.

Finally, $x = y + z$, since $x$ is the length of both adjacent sides put together, so:

$x = \dfrac{100}{\sqrt{3}} + 100\sqrt{3} = \dfrac{100}{\sqrt{3}} + \dfrac{100\sqrt{3}}{1}*\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}} = \dfrac{100 + 100*3}{\sqrt{3}} = \dfrac{400}{\sqrt{3}}$, which is your final answer.

Here is the picture to help you see what I am doing:

[image: Right Triangle]

Comment: So if we were to rationalize the denominator the answer would be 400√3 /3?

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if you decide to rationalize the denominator (some teachers require that you do, others don't), then the answer is $\dfrac{400\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets take a generic hypotenuse-opposite-adjacent right triangle and divide each side by the length of the opposite side (opposite to angle $t$). This gives us a similar triangle with sides $\csc t$, $1$, and $\cot t$. Next, multiply each side by 100 (see below) to get another similar triangle with a height of $100$, hypotenuse of $100\csc t$, and a horizontal base of $100\cot t$.
[image]

Now we want to apply our result to a $60$ degreed, and a $30$ degreed right triangle, and add the horizontal bases together.

Our result becomes
$$100\cot 60^\circ + 100\cot 30^\circ=100(\sqrt{3}+1/\sqrt{3})=400/\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Both of the current answers utilize trig functions.  I thought I would add an answer that doesn't use trig functions, but rather uses scaling of two $(30,60,90)$ triangles.

We are used to seeing the sides of a $(30, 60, 90)$ triangle being written as $(1, \sqrt{3}, 2)$ (where $1$ is the length opposite to the $30$ degree angle, $\sqrt 3$ is the length opposite to the $60$ degree angle, etc).  We can then scale the side lengths by whatever multiplier we wish.  The diagram below shows how to scale the side lengths appropriately for this problem.

[image: Diagram of scaling]

For the left-hand triangle (top), we choose the multiplier $\frac{100}{\sqrt 3}$ (because the side opposite the $60$ degree angle is $100$ units long).  For the right-hand triangle (bottom), we choose the multiplier $100$ (because the side opposite the $30$ degree angle is $100$ units long).

Thus, the length $x$ can be found easily:
$$x = 100\sqrt{3} + \frac{100}{\sqrt 3} = \frac{400\sqrt{3}}{3}$$